# How I can upload a file into HDFS using WebHDFS REST API

Tags: docker, rest, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I want to upload a file from local server to to HDFS via webHDFS REST API.
Based on the documentation, this operation take two steps:

1. Submit a HTTP PUT request, that return the location

   *HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect [Date: Tue, 06 Jun 2023 10:14:46 GMT, Cache-Control: no-cache, Expires: Tue, 06 Jun 2023 10:14:46 GMT, Date: Tue, 06 Jun 2023 10:14:46 GMT, Pragma: no-cache, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Location: http://fcb6de72d72d:9864/webhdfs/v1/root/EMSI/file.txt?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false, Content-Type: application/octet-stream, Content-Length: 0] [Content-Type: application/octet-stream,Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}*
2. Submit another HTTP PUT request using the URL in the Location header

curl -i -X PUT -T file.txt "http://fcb6de72d72d:9864/webhdfs/v1/root/EMSI/file.txt?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false"

This is what I get:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: fcb6de72d72d

I'm running Hadoop cluster on Docker in Macbook Air M1.

References:
[Issues with Uploading an image to HDFS via webHDFS REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248890/issues-with-uploading-an-image-to-hdfs-via-webhdfs-rest-api)
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

The location returned by first request is using the container id, which cannot be resolved by your host. Replace it with localhost

Alternatively, use `hadoop fs -put` instead of WebHDFS

Comment: I replace it with localhost but is not working ...
For the alternative, my objectif is to deploy an API, but I don't know if I can do it and how using command line

Comment: 1) Replaced how? Your error is caused by Docker, not really the address or WebHDFS itself. Did you forget to port forward the datanode(s)? 2) You can wrap `subprocess.call` in a simple containerized flask app, running on the same docker network

Comment: the location suggest by WebHDFS is http://fcb6de72d72d:9864/webhdfs/v1/root/EMSI/file.txt
but "fcb6de72d72d" is a container ID and it is not recognized, I replace it by localhost but it dosent work

Comment: As mentioned, make sure you have forwarded port 9864 on the datanode container to your host